# Laravel Command no me encuentra el driver de SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo un comando de Laravel que hace conexión a una base de datos en SQL Server, pero al ejecutar el comando me sale esto:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException could not find driver
```

Y he ejecutado la misma consulta desde un Controller y funciona sin problema. Ya tengo instalados los PDO y dll para sql_srv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es muy comun que haya una configuracion distinta de PHP (php.ini) para linea de comandos (CLI) y para el servidor web (apache, etc)

Puedes comprobar por linea de comandos si el modulo sql-server esta activo en modo linea de comandos ejecutando `php -i` (phpinfo) y
encontrar la ruta de `php.ini` en la seccion "Configuration File"

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /ruta/a/php.ini
```

Tambien puedes comprobar aqui si esta cargado efectivamente sql-server (algo como esto):

```
PDO drivers => mysql, pgsql, sqlite, sqlsrv
```

Comparala esta informacion con la misma informacion ejecutando `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` en una pagina del servidor. Si son distintas rutas, aplica la misma configuracion correcta para activar el modulo PDO + sql-server.